# Installing xcode in VirtualBox on windows 8

Tags: xcode, virtual-machine, windows-8.1

Does anyone know how to get xcode on a windows 8 laptop. I have tried virtualbox and installed mavericks and works fine but for some reason xcode keeps failing to download. I tried upgrading to 10.9.4 as well and it still didn't work

Comment: Can you share how you are installing Xcode and the specific error message when that happens?

Answer (score 0):

### Using Virtual Machine, firstly download in your real computer Xcode file and then use this link: http://techsultan.com/share-folder-mac-os-x-windows-7-vmware/

Share your file to access by your Virtual Machine and then install itself.

Comment: Links to potential solutions are always welcome, but please add some details for future visitors in case the link is no longer available.